# Parsing xml with multiple children

Tags: python, xml, dataframe, xml-parsing, elementtree

I'm attempting to parse an xml file with python and it's returning a `AttributeError 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'` on the s_amount line. The xml file has product-id, amount, quantity and price-info for n products (three in the example file) and ideally I'd want to generate a table with one row per product ID and the relevant columns filled in where available (amount, quantity and price-info). There will be multiple rows for product 5340958 as this has multiple quantities.

xml file extract:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<pricebooks xmlns="http:...">
    <pricebook>
        <header pricebook-id="IT21">
            <currency>EUR</currency>
        </header>

        <price-tables>
            <price-table product-id="16780001">
                <amount quantity="1">15.00</amount>
                <price-info>2021</price-info>
            </price-table>

            <price-table product-id="5340958">
                <amount quantity="1">5</amount>
                <amount quantity="2">5</amount>
                <amount quantity="3">50</amount>
            </price-table>

            <price-table product-id="864564543">
                <amount quantity="1">60</amount>
            </price-table>

        </price-tables>
    </pricebook>
</pricebooks>
```

Current python script:

```
import pandas as pd
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et

xtree = et.parse("C:...ITfile.xml")
xroot = xtree.getroot()

df_cols = ["product-id", "quantity", "amount", "price-info"]
rows = []
for pricebook in xroot:
    for element in pricebook[1:]:
        for pricetable in element:
            s_product_id = pricetable.attrib.get("product-id")
            rows.append({"product-id": s_product_id})
            for item in pricetable:
                s_quantity = item.attrib.get("quantity")
                rows.append({"quantity": s_quantity})
                s_amount = item.find("amount").text
                rows.append({"amount": s_amount})

out_df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns = df_cols)
```

Comment: Maybe it should be `s_amount = item.text`? And you have to check if the `item` refers to `<amount>` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this snippet to parse the data from the XML file to DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et


xtree = et.parse("file.xml")
namespaces = {'myprefix':'http:...'}  # <-- this is from <pricebooks xmlns="http:...">

df_cols = ["product-id", "quantity", "amount", "price-info"]
rows = []

for row in xtree.findall('.//myprefix:price-table[@product-id]', namespaces):
    price_info = row.find('.//myprefix:price-info', namespaces)
    if not price_info is None:
        price_info = price_info.text
    for amount in row.findall('.//myprefix:amount[@quantity]', namespaces):
        rows.append(dict(zip(df_cols, [row.attrib.get('product-id'), amount.attrib.get('quantity'), amount.text, price_info])))


df = pd.DataFrame(rows)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  product-id quantity amount price-info
0   16780001        1  15.00       2021
1    5340958        1      5       None
2    5340958        2      5       None
3    5340958        3     50       None
4  864564543        1     60       None
```